# Why does this code crash when compiled with Apple LLVM, but not in LLVM/GCC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, llvm, llvm-gcc

I'm trying to get this code: http://code.google.com/p/switchcontrol/source/browse/trunk/code/AFSwitchControl.m compiling under Apple LLVM in Xcode 4.5.2. It works when compiled with LLVM/GCC, but crashes in the mouseDown method when switched to Apple LLVM on line 198:

```
NSRect knobRect = _AFSwitchControlKnobRectForInsetBackground(slotRect, _offset);
```

Because _offset is not set. It's suppose to be set in the bind method with this line:

```
[self setOffset:(CGFloat)[self state]];
```

But it appears that nothing is being set under LLVM for some reason. My binding call looks like:

```
[control bind:NSValueBinding toObject:self withKeyPath:@"isToggleSwitchOn" options:nil];
```

Any ideas why the control's state is not returning anything under LLVM? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually a few lines above, in the call to _AFSwitchControlPartRects.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSRect textRect, backgroundRect;
    _AFSwitchControlPartRects([self bounds], &textRect, &backgroundRect);

    NSRect slotRect = _AFSwitchControlInsetBackgroundRect(backgroundRect);
    NSRect knobRect = _AFSwitchControlKnobRectForInsetBackground(slotRect, _offset);
```

The second argument to _AFSwitchControlPartRects, &textRect is a pointer to a rect.

However in the implementation of the function, that parameter is supposed to be a pointer to enough space for *two* rects.

```
NS_INLINE void _AFSwitchControlPartRects(NSRect bounds, NSRect *textRects, NSRect *backgroundRect) {
    NSDivideRect(bounds, textRects, backgroundRect, NSWidth(bounds)/5.0, NSMinXEdge);

    textRects[1] = _AFSwitchControlInsetTextRect(NSOffsetRect(textRects[0], NSWidth(*backgroundRect), 0));
    textRects[0] = _AFSwitchControlInsetTextRect(textRects[0]);
```

When this writes to textRects[1], it's scribbling on -mouseDown's stack. Buffer overflow.

It looks to me like it's happening to clobber self, so the next dereference of self will die. This happens to be the use of _offset.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to NSRect textRect[2] and called _AFSwitchControlPartRects([self bounds], textRect, &backgroundRect) instead.